# How to check actual RAM usage of tmpfs?

Tags: linux, swap, ram, tmpfs

I know that `tmpfs` falls back to using swap if system is under memory pressure. I can query total `tmpfs` usage in KiB with

```
df | grep tmpfs | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum = sum + $3} END{print sum}'
```

but how to figure out **how much actual RAM is used by `tmpfs` and how much of that is on the swap?**

(Some people claim that `free -m` shows this in `Shared` but that obviously counts a lot more because it may have bigger number than total `tmpfs` usage.)

Comment: Related but simpler question: https://superuser.com/questions/542736/how-to-find-size-of-ram-cache-use-for-ramfs-tmpfs