# Swap is full, but processes barely use any of it

Tags: linux, swap

I have a Debian VM where after about a day (but sometimes sooner) all the swap gets used up (and consequently zabbix pesters me about it). I set `swappiness` to `0`, but it still does this, albeit maybe a little slower.

The most interesting thing is, that if I list the swap usage of processes (either by top or a [script](https://gist.github.com/pallinger/bed9254f185311b9d39824fac0416d8a)) and add them up, I only get about 55MB instead of the 1022MB that is reported as used by `free`.

What could be the cause of the discrepancy between swap usage by adding up individual process swap usages and total reported swap usage?

OS: Debian 10.11
Linux: 4.19.0-18-amd64

Comment: wild guess: swapped kernelspace memory, not belonging to any process in particular?

Comment: @Marcus memory allocated by the kernel can’t be swapped out.

Comment: @StephenKitt is kernel memory automatically pinned?

Comment: @Marcus that depends on what you mean by “pinned”; I’m not sure what more to say than what’s in my previous comment.

Comment: @StephenKit Actually, is was tmpfs memory, which is managed by the kernel and not any process in particular (kdevtmpfs would be a candidate, but (as any kernel process) it does not report any memory usage)

Comment: Yup, I mentioned that in my answer ;-). And I get your point about it being kernel memory, but it’s not kernel-*space* memory. So my comment above isn’t quite accurate since this is allocated by the kernel...

Answer (score 3):

`top`’s swap usage estimates and `/proc`’s `VmSwap` field (which is what the linked script uses) are extremely unreliable.

To get a decent estimate of actual swap usage, you need to look at `/proc/…/smaps`; [`smem`](https://www.selenic.com/smem/) can do that for you, *e.g.*

```
sudo smem -s swap -r|head
```

will show the top swap users, and

```
sudo smem -t
```

will show the total allocated swap in the summary line at the bottom (as accounted for by `smaps`).

Note that this can be inaccurate too, but it should give a better result. Swap can be accounted for multiple times, in which case it is overcounted in the summary line, and some content in swap is apparently not assigned to a single process (*e.g.* swapped-out `tmpfs`), in which case it is undercounted.

Comment: smem seems to give somewhat greater values, though it is still not enough _by far_. `smem -t` reports 247008k total swap usage when `free` reports 1017864k (and the previous script reports 60964k).

Comment: How much data do you have in your `tmpfs`s?

Comment: You may be onto something, `/run/log/journal` has almost 1GB of data. It may be the thing that gets swapped out. It would be nice to have some way to know for sure, though (without actually deleting files from there).

Comment: I confimed `/run/log/journal` as the culprit by editing the journald config and rotating (and thus deleting most) journals. Still, it would be nice to have a tool to list tmpfs swap usage.

Comment: Yes, it would; if I come across one I’ll update this...

Comment: related, unanswered question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585315/how-to-check-actual-ram-usage-of-tmpfs